# Do a custom query search in wordpress by post meta

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm doing a custom search in wordpress, and I would like to find my custom type articles by searching them from custom meta keys.

This code filters posts by custom types, but filters all of them by custom metas, showing no results!

```
function filtri_di_ricerca( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if (is_home())
    {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post_annunci');  
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 1000);

        $meta_query = array();

        // Only check these form fields
        $fields = array( 'annuncio_contratto', 'annuncio_categorie', 'annuncio_tipologia', 'annuncio_citta', 'annuncio_prezzo');
        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            if( $_GET[$field] != '' ) {
                // We have something to match, otherwise ignore the field...
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => $field,
                    'value' => $_GET[$field], 
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
        }
        $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';

        $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
    }

    return;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filtri_di_ricerca');
```

The search address is:

```
http://example.com/?annuncio_contratto=Vendita&annuncio_categorie=Residenziale&annuncio_tipologia=Appartamento&annuncio_citta=NewYork
```

DEBUG with:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($wp_query->query_vars); echo "</pre>";
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [error] => 
    [m] => 0
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [pagename] => 
    [page_id] => 0
    [second] => 
    [minute] => 
    [hour] => 
    [day] => 0
    [monthnum] => 0
    [year] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [category_name] => 
    [tag] => 
    [cat] => 
    [tag_id] => 
    [author_name] => 
    [feed] => 
    [tb] => 
    [paged] => 0
    [comments_popup] => 
    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [preview] => 
    [s] => 
    [sentence] => 
    [fields] => 
    [menu_order] => 
    [category__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_type] => post_annunci
    [posts_per_page] => 1000
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => annuncio_contratto
                    [value] => Vendita
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => annuncio_categorie
                    [value] => Residenziale
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [key] => annuncio_tipologia
                    [value] => Appartamento
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key] => annuncio_citta
                    [value] => Pesaro
                    [compare] => =
                )

            [relation] => AND
        )

    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [cache_results] => 1
    [update_post_term_cache] => 1
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
    [nopaging] => 
    [comments_per_page] => 50
    [no_found_rows] => 
    [order] => DESC
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function filtri_di_ricerca( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    if (is_home())
    {
       $query->set('post_type', 'post_annunci');  // added
       $query->set('posts_per_page', 1000);  //added
       $meta_query = array();  //edited

        // Only check these form fields
        $fields = array( 'annuncio_contratto', 'annuncio_categorie', 'annuncio_tipologia', 'annuncio_citta', 'annuncio_prezzo');

        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
           if( isset($_GET[$field]) and $_GET[$field] != '' ) {     // ADDED isset()
               // We have something to match, otherwise ignore the field...
               $meta_query[] = array(
                   'key' => $field,
                   'value' => $_GET[$field], 
                   'compare' => '=',    // CHANGED
               );
           }
       }
       $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';   // ADDED


    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
    }

    return;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filtri_di_ricerca');
```

## EDIT

You went wrong when you put main query data and meta query data in the same basket.

Comment: still no results im trying to print the query with <?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>
but it doesn't give me much clues....
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dli_wp_posts.* FROM dli_wp_posts INNER JOIN dli_wp_postmeta ON (dli_wp_posts.ID = dli_wp_postmeta.post_id) INNER JOIN dli_wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON

Comment: Give me the rest of this: "`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dli_wp_posts.* FROM dli_wp_posts INNER JOIN dli_wp_postmeta ON (dli_wp_posts.ID = dli_wp_postmeta.post_id) INNER JOIN dli_wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON`"...
Also, commenting system doesn't allow to many comments between two men, so I have to remove some previous comments.

Comment: added debug support ^^
Should i add $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?
i'm not shure if it make sense with adding a 'pre_get_posts' action

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. I believe that you know where is that action activated: only on the home page. Maybe it can be wrong, because you have condition `if(is_home())` and in that case maybe homepage is queried (which I can't know that remotely). Remove that condition and open/closing braces ofc and try if you will see some posts on the place you expect them.

Comment: That was REQUEST you wrote to me - because of that, it's NOT complete, I asked you to paste it all :D (look at your second comment please)

Comment: it's intended to work only in homepage.
if i remove all the code for meta filters and i put this:
$query->set('meta_key','annuncio_contratto');
$query->set('meta_value',$_GET['annuncio_contratto']);
works perfect!
BUT i need to filter more than one meta field.
I appreciate your help, but i think you're looking for something that has nothing to do with it

Comment: My work is done here. Read the codex more. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: i found the problem, the meta-keys i was comparing were incorrect, now it works! Thanks a lot for your help!